# How to pass the date parameter in pyspark query using Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

I want to pass the date parameter in below query in jupyter notebook but its not working as the way its mentioned below. Dont know where the problem is lying.

```
filedate = '2022-11-15'

query = """(select * from db.xyz
        where name = 'Tom'
        and login = '{filedate}') as salary"""

 df = spark.read.format("jdbc")\
                          .option("url", jdbc_url)\
                          .option("driver",jdbc_driver)\
                          .option("dbtable" ,query).load()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an [`f-string`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/):

```
filedate = '2022-11-15'

query = f"""(select * from db.xyz
        where name = 'Tom'
        and login = '{filedate}') as salary"""
```